# Pure CSS way of making button have 2 click state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so quite simply then,

I want to use some css animation classes for a bunch of submenu items and wondered if i could use css in some way to allow for a click active state and a deactive state.  This way i could use a couple of interesting classses with my menu items.

this is an example of a href tag that goes to the div id overview also posted below.  I use jquery to an extent but want to make something pure css for menu items if it is possible.

```
 <a class='slide' href='#' data-url='who-are.html' data-target='mission'>
        <span class='element'>Mission and Values</span>
      </a>


    <div id ="overview" class="animated bounceInUp">some content</div>
```

**So on click of href bring up the div classes... I want to add a class to it if a different menu item is clicked**

Answer (score 1):

It does basically the same.

***HTML:***

```
<input type="checkbox" id="status" />
<label for="status" class="button">
    <button>Button</button>
</label>
```

***CSS:***

```
#status {
    display: none;
}
label {
    background-color: magenta;
    display: inline-block;
}
.button > button {
    pointer-events: none;
    padding: 8px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

#status:not(:checked) ~ .button > button {
    background-color: red;
}
#status:checked ~ .button > button {
    background-color: green;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/339rxdvp/1/)

Comment: thaks for the answer but that is actually two buttons not one

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question at first, but I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple really ...

simply use css focus to allow for two states of a button ! eg

```
button {
    color: red;
}

button:focus {
    color: blue;
}
```